# Deploying asp.net website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I have to send my project to other guy so that he can host it using His IIS. What files should I send to that guy. Should I export it or should I just give him the folder. The other guy doesn't know .NET. Help guys

Comment: You can follow the steps mentioned by Davide Piras. Tip: If you are using any 3rd party dll's remember to mark them "Copy Local"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should do right click on the web project inside your Visual Studio solution explorer and select **Publish**.

this will generated all and only needed files with no source code and compiled assemblies and you can hand over this to the IIS folks.